# Python : get id of dynamic TextInput

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`. i run `test.py` then screen looks like attached image.When i click on `ok` button then I am trying to get `id` of `TextInput` using this code.

```
for row in reversed(rows.children):
    for ch in reversed(row.children):
        if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
            print(ch.id)
            if ch.text == "" and ch.id=='test1':
                print("TextInput is required")
                ch.focus = True
                break;
```

But `print(ch.id)` shows `None` .Can someone tell me how to get `id` of textInput?
If i can get `id` then i can ignore `value2` for blank value.

[image]

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert(self):

        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    print(ch.id)
                    if ch.text == "" and ch.id=='test1':
                        print("TextInput is required")
                        ch.focus = True
                        break;

class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def count_row(self):
        print('count row')


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root

test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    test1 : test1
    test2 : test2
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        id : test1
        size_hint_x: .4

    TextInput:
        id : test2
        size_hint_x: .4
display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value1"
                valign: 'bottom'
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value2"
                valign: 'bottom'

        Rows:
            id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 2):

from https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html:

```
id Added in 1.0.0
Unique identifier of the widget in the tree.

id is a StringProperty and defaults to None.
```

You can assign a running **id** yourself though...